# Capturar todos los errores JavaScript en Angular2

Tags: javascript, angularjs-2.0

Como dice el titulo, estoy necesitando capturar todos los errores generados en JavaScript pero mediante angular.

La idea es levantar un servicio que envíe los errores que llegaran a suceder del lado del cliente para tener un log de errores en el servidor, para después corregirlos.

Si fuese JavaScript, sólo funcionarían cosas como

```
window.onerror = MyErrorHandler()
```

En angular hay una clase **`ErrorHandler`** que se puede extender pero sólo captura los errores que se generan en angular.

Necesito capturar todos por más insignificante que sea.

Comment: Tu aplicacion en Angular2 esta hecha en Javascript o en Typescript? Seria bueno saber la version exacta de angular 2 que estas usando.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Con **Angular 2** se introdujo Typescript como el lenguaje más adecuado para escribir una aplicacion con angular 2. Siendo el caso, uno puede practicamente eliminar los errores mas *triviales*  de javascript activando *la compilacion Ahead of Time*.

Si estan usando el **@angular/cli** esto se hace a traves del parametro **aot=true**

```
$> ng build --aot=true
```

> Activando esta caracteristica descartamos los errores como enlaces de datos incorrectos en las vistas, o uso de datos no compatibles tales como tratar de enlazar un evento a un objeto y no a una funcion.

Por ejemplo:

```
import {Http} from '@angular/http';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app works!';

  constructor(private http:Http){    
  }

  errorFunc = 34;

}
```

Y en la vista de nuestro componente :

```
<h1>
  {{title}}
</h1>
<p>
 <button (click)="errorFunc()" >Please dont touch me</button>
</p>
```

Si compilamos nuestra aplicacion de la manera tradicional (aot=false) no recibimos ningun error hasta que usemos el boton de nuestra aplicacion, pero si compilamos con la compilacion Ahead of Time obtendremos lo siguiente:

[image: Error en compilacion AOT]

### Para la mayoria de los errores

Tu puedes usar la clase `ErrorHandler` de `@angular/core`para manejar casi cualquier error que surja durante la ejecucion de nuestra aplicacion angular 2 sobreescribiendo el metodo `handleError(error:Error):void`. Vale la pena mencionar que yo uso esta clase justamente para enviar errores del lado cliente a un servidor(Raygun) :)

Por ejemplo, para mostrar los errores como notificaciones:

```
import { Injectable, ErrorHandler  } from '@angular/core';
import {NotificationsService, SimpleNotificationsComponent} from 'angular2-notifications';

@Injectable()
export class MyAppErrorHandler extends ErrorHandler {

  constructor(private _toastService: NotificationsService,){
    super(false);    
  }
  
  public handleError(error: Error):void
  {    
    //do somethign with the error    
    //for example show a toast
    this._toastService.error("Error","An error has ocurred");      
  };
}
```

Y finalmente lo registras a nivel de tu aplicacion:

```
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { MyAppErrorHandler } from './error-handling';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    imports: [       
    ],
    providers: [         
        { provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: MyAppErrorHandler }      
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Referencia : https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ErrorHandler-class.html

### Si quieres llegar mas lejos

Podemos *hackear* Zone.js para capturar los errores que suceden al ejecutarse en ese contexto introduciendo el siguiente fragmento en el **index.html** de nuestra aplicacion.

```
<script>

  Zone.current._zoneDelegate.handleError = function () {
      console.log("Error handled by ZoneJS :: " + arguments);
  };

</script>
```

[image: Erro handled by Zone.js]

> Cabe resaltar lo no documentado de este proceso y lo suceptible al cambio en caso Zone.js cambie la forma en la que trabaja ademas del hecho de no poder usar las clases de Angular 2 en este contexto.

Referencia: https://github.com/angular/zone.js

Comment: Claro mencione tal implementación al final de extender **ErrorHandler** pero realmente no captura todo lo que necesito por ejemplo omite errores que no son lanzados por zone.js

Comment: Quizás te sirva esto: https://blog.sentry.io/2016/06/27/sentry-and-angular2.html.

Comment: genial esto me aclaro un monton de cosas